# Value of type '(CGFloat, CGFloat) -> CGRect' has no member 'origin'

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use `CGRect.insetBy( dx : ... , dy : ...)` but the code gives me an error which can't be solved at all.

```
func scaleRect (rect: CGRect , xScale : CGFloat, yScale : CGFloat , offset : CGPoint) -> (CGRect){
    let width = rect.width
    let height = rect.height
    let scaleUp : CGFloat = 2.0

    var newWidth  = sqrt(width * width * scaleUp)
    var newHeight = sqrt(height * height * scaleUp)


    var newRect = rect.insetBy(dx: (width - newWidth)/2, dy: (height - newHeight)/2)
          // error here ***  Value of type '(CGFloat, CGFloat) -> CGRect' has no member 'origin'

    var resultRect = CGRect(x: newRect.origin.x, y: newRect.origin.y, width: newRect.size.width, height: newRect.size.height)

    resultRect = CGRect.offsetBy(resultRect, offset.x , offset.y)
    return resultRect
}
```

Comment: Your code gives me a completely different error on a completely different line. What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Error is here,     resultRect = CGRect.offsetBy(resultRect, offset.x , offset.y)

Comment: @PPL is right in your use of `offsetBy` is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **`offsetBy`** like this according to Swift,

```
let rect = resultRect.offsetBy(dx: offset.x, dy: offset.y)
```

Learn more about [insetBy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454218-insetby) and [offsetBy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454841-offsetby) and [CGGeometry](http://nshipster.com/cggeometry/)

Comment: `offsetBy` is different from `insetBy`

Comment: Thank you for your information, I know it :) I am solving error for above code only

Comment: but maybe he doesn't want to use `offsetBy` instead of `insetBy`

Comment: @arash when you try to compile the code, the compile error occurs on the `offsetBy` line, not the `insetBy` line.

Comment: @arash Did you actually copy the OP's code into Xcode? The OP's code has no error where they claim. The posted code has a different error on a different line. This answer fixes the actual problem, not the posted (and non-existent) problem.

Comment: Oh wow thanks very much , seem the old style need to input 3 parameters  CGRect(rect , dx , dy) while the new api only require 2  rect( dx , dy) .